# libxml for c program in ubuntu

Tags: c, ubuntu, libxml2

I want to use libxml2 as parser for a c program on a system with ubuntu. I used the following command to install libxml2:

```
sudo apt-get install -y libxml2-dev
```

I try to compile the following file: http://xmlsoft.org/examples/reader1.c
My makefile looks like this:

```
xml_reader: xml_reader.o
    gcc -o xml_reader xml_reader.o -lxml2 -lm
    
xml_reader.c: xml_reader.c
    gcc -c xml_reader.c -I/usr/include/libxml2
```

But sadly I get the following response:

```
fatal error: libxml/xmlreader.h: No such file or directory
```

Did I miss something, which I had to do before compiling or am I even using the right -l argument?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The target of your second Makefile rule should be `xml_reader.o` and not `xml_reader.c`. Right now make is using a default rule instead which does not make use of `-I/usr/include/libxml2` and thus gcc cannot find the required header.